# How to understand risk of a hosting ISP private network?

Tags: network, risk-analysis, isp

I am trying to understand the security concerns related to using the private network provided by my hosting ISPs.

The ISPs offer a private network feature that only my VPS instances are connected to. The private networks only support IPv4 and only servers within the same physical location.

I am already trusting the ISP with the servers, themselves, so what I'm not clear on is how to assess risk of the additional configurations to encrypt between servers on the private network (yes, these are are not significantly complex or intrusive configurations, until and unless I forget to renew a cert, or something similar) vs. risk of not encrypting between the servers.

Here is one example of what I am considering:

One server with a reverse proxy from its public facing interface to its private facing interface on the private network. Another server on the private network has an application with no TLS functionality. I can add a reverse proxy to the application server so the connection from the network reverse proxy is encrypted, but now I'm adding a thing and wondering what I am doing this to protect myself from.

Some relatively simple things other than encryption and authentication I know can do include a static ARP table, blocking bogons on public facing interfaces, and allowing connections from specific IP address to local ports, but I would configure these regardless.

Comment: So, is your question about the risk of ***hosting*** or the risk of ***not encrypting***? You appear to switch your question. And you also seem to switch from risk analysis to mitigations.  Are you wanting a risk analysis of the situation or the mitigations (inherent vs residual risks)?

Comment: @schroeder I tried to make the question about trusting a hosted private network, as I would interpret not trusting to mean I should encrypt, and vice-versa. I thought that providing a specific example might help with what I'm trying to understand, but I didn't intend to imply those were mitigations for an ISP trust issue.